# Frameworks, Delegates and View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building a framework for third party developers. The way i am building is I have a created a static iOS project and followed the steps listed [here](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework). Now I added the following stuff to that framework example:

Added a ViewController to the Framework Project

The main public class of the project has a delegate that the third party developers will implement

Now what I need to implement is say for example, the third party developer uses my framework and sets the delegate to their app's class.What I want my framework to do is present a view controller on top of their view showing the desired content. 
It turns out that the main class in the framework project is a NSObject class and doesn't support methods like `presentModalViewController` etc.

So could you suggest a way of achieving the above said purpose, i.e., my framework should present a view controller above the delegate's view. Also, I am creating my view controller using interface builder in the framework project. Please suggest if that's the right approach or not. If not, how do you reckon i design the layout of the view that I need on top of calling view - purely by code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should follow the pattern of [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) and several others in the standard SDK.  That means your framework would provide public class that *is* a subclass of UIViewController.

```
#import <MyFramework/MyFrameworkViewController.h>

@interface CustomerViewController : UIViewController <MyFrameworkViewControllerDelegate>
@end

- (IBAction)pressedShowFrameworkVC:(id)sender {

    MyFrameworkViewController *frameworkVC = [[MyFrameworkViewController alloc] init];
    // your framework init can init from your bundle's nib
    frameworkVC.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:frameworkVC animated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

Your framework vc dismisses itself when the user finishes with it.

```
// MyFrameworkViewController.m

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion^{
    [self.delegate frameworkVC:self didFinishWithStuff:@"Done"];
}];
```

Your customer implements this...

```
- (void)frameworkVC:(MyFrameworkViewController *)frameworkVC didFinishWithStuff:(NSString *)objectDescribingCompletionState {

}
```

**EDIT** - Suppose your framework also needs to do some non-viewcontroller related work for the customer app.  It can still provide a subclass of NSObject (or NSURLConnection or whatever) as another public class.

```
// CustomerViewController.m
#import <MyFramework/MyFrameworkWorkerBee.h>

- (IBAction)pressedMakeMyFrameworkDoSomethingUseful:(id)sender {

    MyFrameworkWorkerBee *workerBee = [[MyFrameworkWorkerBee alloc] init];
    [workerBee fetchStuffFromTheWebWithCompletion:^(id result) {
        // now present results
        MyFrameworkViewController *frameworkVC = [[MyFrameworkViewController alloc] init];
        frameworkVC.delegate = self;
        frameworkVC.resultsToPresent = results;
        [self presentViewController:frameworkVC animated:YES completion:^{}];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. However, consider the scenario that the app calls my framework. What I want is the app sets itself as a delegate to my framework and tell the framework to start working. What the framework will do then is communicate with a web server to get the data that has to be displayed. When the data has arrived, the framework should display a view controller over the calling delegate's view, which is when the user interacts..
The example above presents my framework's view immediately, which is not required.. :(

Comment: Yeah, I anticipated this kind of reply whilst answering.  I'll rephrase as, "But my framework needs to do some other stuff that isn't view controller related".  The answer is - your framework can contain many classes (even on related ones) for your customer to use.  Will edit my answer now to elaborate.

Comment: Okay I applied whatever you mentioned above and tried implementing a basic & simple app. But turns out that I am getting a _framework not found error_ But when I am importing the headers of the framework into this simple program, it is importing correctly (auto complete is working as well)..But when I run the code, it fails saying framework not found.

Comment: Sorry to hear.  That's an entirely different question than what logical interface pattern should it provide.  I'd suggest a careful review of the github instructions.  See this issue:  https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework/issues/19